# unison-fsmonitor fails on BashOnWindows

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, bash, unison, inotify

When running Unison on BashOnWindows, I receive the following error when trying to run in file watching mode:

`Fatal error: Filesystem watcher error: unexpected error 22 while adding a watcher
The watcher can be disabled by setting preference 'watch' to false`

I am syncing a directory that contains only 1 file. Any thoughts on what might be the issue?

Comment: Which version of the Subsystem are you running?  If your running 1703 be sure you manually update your existing Subsystem it won't happen automatically

Comment: @Ramhound It looks like I am running version 1607 of Windows 10 (I found this in the about section under system settings). Is this different from subsystem version?

Comment: Yes; 1607 runs Ubuntu 14 I think where as 1703 runs Ubuntu 16, I read the information over a week ago, so I am not entirely sure.  Anyways the point is, it only matters if you were running 1703, as you can't upgrade the Subsystem until you install the 1703 feature update.

Comment: According to [uservoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/13469097-support-for-filesystem-watchers-like-inotify) *"inotify support was added in Win10 Insiders build #14942"*